# Create an Index Chart in R - relative starting point

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I need to look at relative change in 2 groups of data which have very different scales.
I would therefore think that by setting my first value to 100% and then creating a proportion to that value per group is the way forward.  I can then create a line chart to show the relative movement.
I would call this an index chart so may have missed existing questions.

However I don't know how to set my data up in R to do this.

My aggregated data below.  I  want each of 1999 to be 100% and the subsequent years to be % of that.

```
> Totals
  year  fips Emissions
1 1999 06037 6109.6900
2 2002 06037 7188.6802
3 2005 06037 7304.1149
4 2008 06037 6421.0170
5 1999 24510  403.7700
6 2002 24510  192.0078
7 2005 24510  185.4144
8 2008 24510  138.2402
```

I'm probably going to want to add a bar chart behind it to show weighting too as relative change is much more dramatic for smaller data.  Tips on that are appreciated too but I've not searched for that yet as the above is the primary issue IMO.

Appreciate your help.
James

Comment: Thank you bergant.  That's sorted it.  However when I create the plot my x values are autoselected as 2000 and up by 2 years.  I've tried to adjust this with scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:4),labels=c("1999" etc) but I then get no labels at all... Can you advise?

Answer (score 2):

For example with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- 
  df1 %>% 
    group_by(fips) %>% 
    mutate(ind = Emissions / first(Emissions))
```

And using ggplot2 to plot a line chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = ind, color = as.factor(fips))) +
  geom_line()
```